# Multiple references within a single citation with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing

What I would like to do is to have a single citation that contains multiple references. Something like:

```
    \cite{reference1}
```

That would show on text like this:

Here we are citing reference1.<sup>1</sup>

But in the References section would be like this:

1. a) Paper 1; b) Paper 2; c) Paper 3; and so forth.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `\ref` is used for references inside your text ("see page x"), not for references to other works. You want to use the command `\footnote`. When you want to cite several works in one footnote you can use the `biblatex` package and use the command `\footcites`.

Comment: You're right about \ref. Just fixed it the original post. I don't want a footnote. What I want is to have them at the References section all under a single citation.

Comment: I can see the advantage of citing several related pieces in a single citation call-out, but I fail to see why anyone would want to group these pieces in a single *entry* in the bibliography. In which field is your research based in?

Comment: @Mico Common in chemistry and I believe physics too. (Life gets really fun when people want to cite individual entries within such a group, or to intersperse the references with notes about them!)

Comment: @jo This is indeed common in physics, not sure why. I think it's common because when people cite many articles, I) they don't know how to compress the reference from [1,2,3,4...,n] to [1-n], and Ii) it saves space in the bibliography because you don't need newlines for every item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For 'traditional' BibTeX, the `mcite` and `mciteplus` packages both offer this ability with suitable-set-up `.bst` files. An example using my own `rsc` bundle:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Arduengo1992,
  Title                    = {Electronic stabilization of nucleophilic carbenes},
  Author                   = {Arduengo, III, Anthony J. and H.~V.~Rasika Dias and Richard~L. Harlow and Michael Kline},
  Journal                  = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  Year                     = {1992},
  Number                   = {14},
  Pages                    = {5530--5534},
  Volume                   = {114},

  Doi                      = {10.1021/ja00040a007},
}
@Article{Arduengo1994,
  Title                    = {Low-coordinate carbene complexes of nickel(0) and platinum(0)},
  Author                   = {Arduengo, III, Anthony J. and Siegfried~F. Gamper and Joseph~C. Calabrese and Fredric Davidson},
  Journal                  = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  Year                     = {1994},
  Number                   = {10},
  Pages                    = {4391--4394},
  Volume                   = {116},

  Doi                      = {10.1021/ja00089a029},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{mciteplus}
\begin{document}
Some text \cite{Arduengo1992,*Arduengo1994}.
\bibliographystyle{rsc}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

With biblatex/biber, sets can be defined without problem in the bib and dynamically:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[subentry]{biblatex}
\defbibentryset{set2}{shore,doody}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{set}, \cite{set2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]